# Trouble Adding to an Object in an ArrayList

Tags: java, object, arraylist

I've been working on an inventory application, I'm trying to add a price, quantity, description, and name to an object in a list.

Netbeans now says it cannot find 'symbol: method ProductInfo(String, String, int, int)'.

This is the code the problem is on line **258**:

```
import java.util.*;

//NO CLASS

/**
 *
 * @author matthewmurchison
 */
public class mVentoryHome extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form mVentoryHome
     */
    public mVentoryHome() {
        initComponents();

     }

        public class ProductInfo{
        String name, des;
        int ID, num;

    }

        /**
     *
     */
    public static void Inventory(){

        }


    //creat Array
        ArrayList <ProductInfo> Inventory = new ArrayList <ProductInfo> ();

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        IDIn = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        NameIn = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        DesOut = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        IDOut = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        NameOut = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        AddGo = new javax.swing.JButton();
        NameGo = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        IDGo = new javax.swing.JButton();
        Title = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        NameSearch = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        IDSearch = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        DesIn = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        NumIn = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        NumOut = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        Title1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        Title2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
        setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
        setEnabled(false);

        AddGo.setText("Add");
        AddGo.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                AddGoActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        NameGo.setText("Search Name");
        NameGo.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                NameGoActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
        jLabel1.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabel1.setText("Name");

        IDGo.setText("Search ID #");
        IDGo.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                IDGoActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        Title.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/mVentory Logo Small.png"))); // NOI18N

        jLabel5.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
        jLabel5.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabel5.setText("ID #");

        jLabel4.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
        jLabel4.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabel4.setText("Name");

        jLabel3.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
        jLabel3.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabel3.setText("Description");

        jLabel2.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
        jLabel2.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabel2.setText("ID #");

        jLabel6.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
        jLabel6.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabel6.setText("Number");

        Title1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
        Title1.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        Title1.setText("Add Items");

        Title2.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
        Title2.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        Title2.setText("Search Items");

        org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout layout = new org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
            .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .add(101, 101, 101)
                .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
                    .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .add(157, 157, 157)
                        .add(IDOut, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 103, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .add(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.TRAILING, layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
                        .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .add(NameOut, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 103, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.RELATED)
                            .add(NumOut, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 40, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .add(DesOut, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 260, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .add(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .add(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(68, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
                    .add(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.TRAILING)
                            .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.TRAILING)
                                    .add(jLabel3)
                                    .add(jLabel2)
                                    .add(jLabel1)
                                    .add(jLabel6))
                                .add(18, 18, 18)
                                .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
                                    .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                        .add(6, 6, 6)
                                        .add(AddGo, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 163, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                    .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING, false)
                                        .add(NumIn)
                                        .add(DesIn)
                                        .add(IDIn)
                                        .add(NameIn, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 235, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))))
                            .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.TRAILING)
                                    .add(jLabel4)
                                    .add(jLabel5))
                                .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
                                    .add(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.TRAILING, NameSearch, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 235, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                    .add(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.TRAILING, layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING, false)
                                        .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING, false)
                                            .add(IDGo, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                            .add(NameGo, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 163, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                        .add(IDSearch, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 235, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))))
                        .add(84, 84, 84))
                    .add(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .add(Title2, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 163, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .add(133, 133, 133))
                    .add(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.TRAILING)
                            .add(Title)
                            .add(Title1, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 163, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .add(125, 125, 125))))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
            .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .add(Title)
                .add(79, 79, 79)
                .add(Title1)
                .add(27, 27, 27)
                .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.TRAILING)
                    .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .add(NameIn, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .add(16, 16, 16)
                        .add(IDIn, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .add(18, 18, 18)
                        .add(DesIn, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .add(18, 18, 18)
                        .add(NumIn, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .add(jLabel1)
                        .add(16, 16, 16)
                        .add(jLabel2)
                        .add(18, 18, 18)
                        .add(jLabel3)
                        .add(18, 18, 18)
                        .add(jLabel6)))
                .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.RELATED)
                .add(AddGo)
                .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.RELATED, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .add(Title2)
                .add(40, 40, 40)
                .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
                    .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .add(jLabel4)
                        .add(46, 46, 46)
                        .add(jLabel5))
                    .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .add(NameSearch, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.RELATED)
                        .add(NameGo)
                        .add(11, 11, 11)
                        .add(IDSearch, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .add(18, 18, 18)
                        .add(IDGo)))
                .add(93, 93, 93)
                .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
                    .add(NameOut, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 22, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .add(IDOut, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 22, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .add(NumOut, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 22, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .add(18, 18, 18)
                .add(DesOut, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 22, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .add(66, 66, 66))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void AddGoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
        // Add Item
        String Name, Description;
        int Identification, Number;

        Name = NameIn.getText();
        Description = DesIn.getText();
        Identification = Integer.parseInt(IDIn.getText());
        Number = Integer.parseInt(NumIn.getText());

        Inventory.add(ProductInfo(Name, Description, Identification, Number));


    }                                     

    private void NameGoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
        // Search by Name


    }                                      

    private void IDGoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
        // Search by ID
    }                                    



    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {






        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(mVentoryHome.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(mVentoryHome.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(mVentoryHome.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(mVentoryHome.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new mVentoryHome().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton AddGo;
    private javax.swing.JTextField DesIn;
    private javax.swing.JLabel DesOut;
    private javax.swing.JButton IDGo;
    private javax.swing.JTextField IDIn;
    private javax.swing.JLabel IDOut;
    private javax.swing.JTextField IDSearch;
    private javax.swing.JButton NameGo;
    private javax.swing.JTextField NameIn;
    private javax.swing.JLabel NameOut;
    private javax.swing.JTextField NameSearch;
    private javax.swing.JTextField NumIn;
    private javax.swing.JLabel NumOut;
    private javax.swing.JLabel Title;
    private javax.swing.JLabel Title1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel Title2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: post the code that you have

Comment: Show us your actual code, please. We can't tell you what you're doing wrong without knowing exactly what you're doing.

Comment: The error must be at line 55, of course ;-)

Comment: @JordanD,I've updated the post to include the code, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting your `arraylist` inside a method means it can only be accessed by the method it is in and is lost when the method is finished running. You have two options.

1. Change the return type of your method as an `arraylist` and return and manipulate your `arraylist`
2. Create the `arraylist` outside of a method global to the whole class.

This code block should help:

```
 public class mVentoryHome extends javax.swing.JFrame {
      private static ArrayList <ProductInfo> Inventory = new ArrayList<ProductInfo>();
}
```

Comment: Those worked! Thanks! Now netbeans can't find the method ProductInfo, on the last line below... "// Add Item
        String Name, Description;
        int Identification, Number;
        
        Name = NameIn.getText();
        Description = DesIn.getText();
        Identification = Integer.parseInt(IDIn.getText());
        Number = Integer.parseInt(NumIn.getText());
        
        Inventory.add(ProductInfo(Name, Description, Identification, Number));"

Comment: No, I added it after adding your suggestions. Ill add it to the post now.

Comment: I added the new code to the question, its probably a similar problem. But its still beyond me.